# Export filters in eclipse logcat

Tags: android, eclipse, filtering, logcat

Is there any way to export/restore filters for logcat. The reason I'm asking is that i got more then one computer i use and i got a lot of different filters for debug my application so i would like to avoid having to input hundrad of filters manually on each computer.

if this is not possible with the default tool for android development in eclipse is there any other log-plugin for eclipse that got this feature?

I did some googling after this but could not find anything on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the value of `logcat.view.filters.list` in `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs` from one workspace to another and it will both share the same configuration.

Comment: Doesn't this copy all setting? Meaning that some specific setting for this computer has to be redone after the copy. It save some time so better then nothing but having a way to copy only the filters would be preferred.

Comment: My bad misunderstood what you meant.